# Iterating over symmetric matrix in python

Tags: python

I have a symmetric matrix and I want to loop over its elements. Currently, I'm using:

```
import torch

# sample symmetric matrix
W = torch.tensor([[0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [3., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 2.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0.]])

for ix, row in enumerate(W):
    for iy, element in enumerate(row):

        if iy <= ix:
            continue

        print(element)
```

I was wondering whether is this the most efficient way or if it can be written in a better way.

Comment: This matrix doesn't look symmetric. The first row starts with `3., 0., 1.` but the first column starts with `3.0, 0., 0.`

Comment: @vnp That's not the first row . . .

Comment: Why do you omit main diagonal elements from the output?

Comment: @JosefZ Because this symmetric matrix is representing an adjacency matrix for an undirected graph with no self-loops. Having no self-loops means that the node is not connected to itself, so the diagonal is zero anyways and does not need to be processed in the loop in my case. Nothing fancy...